# iOS system permission alert views not showing up in object browser

Tags: ios, ui-automation, testcomplete

I'm attempting to use TestComplete to perform automated tests on an iPad app, but the test is running into trouble with the Location Services permission alert. This alert comes up after logging into the app, but for some reason it is not showing up in the object browser and I have not been able to get TestComplete to handle the alert. However, I can handle the custom alerts elsewhere in the app.

Any advice would be appreciated as I'd like to have these tests running on a fresh build every night but right now I have to manually trigger the alert and dismiss it before running the test. This is obviously not preferred.

EDIT: So I believe I know why this is happening and that's because the AlertView belongs to the application "Springboard" and not to my application. Is there a workaround for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this permission alert is displayed by the system and not by the application, TestComplete does not have access to it and, therefore, cannot put it to the object tree. The only thing you can do to handle this permission alert is simulating a touch action using screen coordinates with the [device.Touch](http://smartbear.com/viewarticle/59702/) method.

Comment: That's what I figured. Very unfortunate!

Comment: Would you happen to have a code sample that supports this? I cannot seem to get it to work by tapping the screen where the button is.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set [the UIAutomation onAlert callback](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Reference/UIATargetClassReference/index.html#//apple_ref/javascript/func/UIATarget/onAlert) to catch the location alert.

```
UIATarget.onAlert = function onAlert(alert) {
    var title = alert.name();
    UIALogger.logDebug("Caught onAlert: " + title);
    if (title.indexOf("Would Like to Use Your Current Location") > -1) {
        alert.buttons()["OK"].tap();
        delay(0.3);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
};
```

Comment: You are correct in your answer but I'm not working with Instruments I'm working with TestComplete. It is a fairly simple fix in Instruments but for some reason TestComplete can't access system alerts because they originate from Springboard and not from the current process. It's an unfortunate feature to be lacking for sure.

Comment: Catching system alerts is a fairly major feature to go missing from a test system.  Does this mean they are unable to test any apps that use location, push notifications, etc?

Comment: I don't want to speak on behalf of the TC team, but it seems like any alert launched from the SpringBoard is unaccessible to the test. The other answer said that you can use screen coordinates to touch where the button is but I haven't been able to successfully do that yet

Comment: Can you share this question with their support team and ask them to weigh in?